# GetUtcOffset returning wrong timezone

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

for some reason when I use the following code

```
 TimeSpan timeDiffUtcServer = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

it returns -07:00:00 offset

I am using Windows XP and my timezone is set to Pacific time -08:00. I am running this through VS 2010's built in IIS server which is on my computer, so I can't figure out why the discrepancy in time.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're experiencing Daylight Saving time, you're only 7 hours behind universal time.  When you go back to standard time, you'll be 8 hours behind again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pacific **Daylight** Time has an offset of -7 hours.

Comment: Dang, I had no idea that checking the Daylight savings time adjusted the timezone offset. Thanks for the help!